# Check if HDF5 Store object is empty?

Tags: python, hdf5, pandas

I am using pandas HDFSTore object to open a hdf5 file and store `DataFrame` objects. But before I do that, I want to find out if the file is empty. Is there a way to find out if my

```
In[12]:
import pandas
store = pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore('store.h5')
Out[12]:
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: store.h5
Empty
```

Is there a way to get a browse the hierarchy tree in store.h5 to check if the object is empty. I would like to get a list of objects in store.h5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
store.keys()
```

to get a list of the stored objects